# Setting parent property from child

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, custom-controls

I would like to know how to set a custom control's property from a style.

I have a custom control based on a togglebutton called 'Substrate' on which I have a dependencyproperty called 'SubstrateState'. It takes an enum as value.

In a seperate file I have a style which adds a context menu to the control.

When the user press on one of the menuitems in the context menu I want the property to trigger with some predefined value.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Substrate}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Substrate}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu Background="#212121">
                        <MenuItem Header="Aborted">
                            <MenuItem.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                                                         Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="{Binding SubstrateState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=local:Substrate}, Converter=converter:StringToSubstrateStatesConverter}"
                                                            Value="Aborted" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </MenuItem.Style>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Grid.ContextMenu>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

When I run this i get:
"Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception."

Inner Exception
"local:Substrate is not a valid value for Int32."

I put breakpoints in my value converter and they never trigger so im thinking the problem is elsewhere.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you provide entire control template ? From my perspective something wrong with your template because I can't even see any Context menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are getting because you are setting AncestorLevel=local:Substrate, while AncestorLevel expects Int32.

Also,  you cannot achieve it the way you are doing. i.e you cannot do binding on the Property of Setter like you are doing as it is not a DependancyProperty. What you can do is to give your `MenuItem` a `Name` and use `ControlTemplate.Trigger` to update your control property in the trigger's setter:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Substrate}">
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Substrate}">
                  <Grid>
                     <Grid.ContextMenu>
                         <ContextMenu Background="#212121">
                              <MenuItem x:Name="myMenuItem" Header="Aborted"> 
                                </MenuItem>
                          </ContextMenu>
                       </Grid.ContextMenu>
                   </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                       <Trigger SourceName="myMenuItem" Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="SubstrateState" Value="Aborted"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                     </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: I did the change and the error is gone. The property still isn't set though. I've tried adding the valueconverter but still nothing.

Comment: i tried it at my end and it worked.. is it giving any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: No nothing, I will write a small project without all the overhead and see if I can get it working. Thanks!

Comment: OK i found what causes me the issue. If I use a binding to to the SubstrateState property I can no longer also set it when pressing the menuitem. I have no solution for this as of yet but will post it as another question. Thanks for your help.